# What is one word for phone number, email address, skype?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

On a web site I have **contact details** section. This section can contain phone number, email address, personal site, etc. And I have button to add new item for contact details.

What is more correct form for 'Add ...'?

Comment: I think contact details is the closest you can get without becoming really obscure.

Comment: To those who downvoted because there was no information about how this phrase would be used, I think that there is. It's for a button a website where a user can add information. The OP says as much with "on a website" and his example sentence of "Add..."

Comment: The title asks for a single word for phone number etc, but the question body asks for an alternative to 'Add ...'. Please clarify what you're asking for, and why your own term, *contact details*, is not appropriate.

Comment: Informally, I ask for a person's **coordinates**. They respond with their preferred specifics.

Comment: @stan I am a native English speaker and wouldn't have a clue what you were asking for if you asked me that

Comment: @Stan If someone were asking for my coordinates, I'd think they were referring to latitude & longitude, as if they were [trying to land a rocket on me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZTCEO0gvLo&feature=youtu.be&t=12m50s) or something like that (link is from earlier today).  "Contact details" or "contact information" or "contact info" seems like the way to go.

Comment: @Stan et al: In French, the word for this is *coordonnées*, i.e., coordinates. In English, it's *contact information*.

Comment: In Switzerland they often use the term coordinates to refer to contact information, but they are not native English speakers, obviously. Is the term connectivity details appropriate?

Comment: OP, do you mean a button out on some main page that takes them to a place where all contact information can be added? Or do you mean a button on the contact info page, that allows them to create *new* categories of info and then fill in their details? I think you mean the second, which is why plain "contact details/info" doesn't work very well, but I'm not sure from your question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think *contact information* is more common than *contact details*, although the latter is defined in [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/contact-details) as:

> the information required to contact someone, such as an address or telephone number

To see that *contact information* is more common than *contact details*, see this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=contact%20information%2Ccontact%20info%2Ccontact%20details&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccontact%20information%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontact%20info%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontact%20details%3B%2Cc0).

These two words comprise a collocation and are immediately understood to mean exactly what you want them to mean. Don't be led on the wild goose chase of looking for a single word when two will do just fine.

Here are some examples of "contact information" being used on websites: [here](http://www.theblaze.com/stories/2016/08/12/hacker-publishes-house-democrats-personal-contact-information/), [here](http://www.ge.com/contact/general), [here](https://www.darienlake.com/contact), and [here](http://www.dell.com/support/Contents/us/en/04/category/Contact-Information?~ck=mn_1).

Answer (score 9):

These days it's quite common to use **"contact info"** (short for contact information already mentioned) which includes e-mail address, phone number, mobile number, skype, facebook username, whatever.

Answer (score 6):

The shortest suggestion I can think of is a shorter form of 'contact information'.

> Contact info

This is also the version that Microsoft utilize in the popular Skype application.

[image: Screenshot from Android Version of Microsoft Skype Application]

Comment: It said this in Skype yeeeears before Microsoft acquired the technology. Just feels wrong to credit MS with the decision.

Answer (score 4):

One more:
Add… **Contact Method**

But go with “Add Contact Details”.

It would be nice if you could just use the single word “Contact”. However, it wouldn’t be proper. That’s why other answers are suggesting “Contact Details” or “Contact Information”.

In the sense of human communication, contact has a few usages.

- **contact** *v.* the act of establishing communication with a second party.
- **contact** *n.* a person whose contact details appear in a directory of people and contact details.
- **contact** *n.* the entry itself in the directory (sometimes called a “contact card”).

To say “Add Contact” would imply adding a new entry/person to the directory.

To say “Add Contact Method” implies opening up a dialogue box where you first choose the **contact method** and then enter the **contact details/information**.

Comment: +1. I *think* the OP is talking about a situation in which some contact info fields are available by default (probably basics like one email address and one phone number), and there is a button that allows users to add more information of their choice (less universal things like a Snapchat username or second email address). If so, I think this is the best answer. "Add Contact **Field**" would also work, but I think *Method* sounds less jargon-y.

Comment: Yes. Nice. **Field** sounds like we’re talking about HTML forms. Which he is.