# Word for all ways of contacting someone

Tags: single-word-requests

I am developing a database application where a user should be able to store multiple ways of contacting someone in a database table.

This database table can for e.g. contain:

- phone numbers
- mobile numbers
- email addresses
- twitter IDs
- facebook IDs
- whatsapp numbers

Now I am looking for a table name. The obvious choice would be **contacts**.
However, the term 'contacts' is used when referring to people and not ways of contacting this person.

I am looking for a single word to describe all ways of contacting a person.

Comment: It's contact information / details. And easily found when doing a tiny bit of research.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is one word for phone number, email address, skype?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/342778/what-is-one-word-for-phone-number-email-address-skype)

Comment: I've seen these called (informally) coordinates.

Comment: ..*ContactMode*

Comment: Also note: naming (including naming of tables) questions usually do not help anyone but the asker. They are off topic unless there is a clearly identified source of concern which would be interesting to many future visitors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

> contact details

If this is too long you could shorten it to 'details' on its own.

Comment: Though not a single word, I prefer contact details. "Details" (alone) is almost too generic, ie ambiguous IMO.

Comment: Yeah that is a fair comment. I just suggested that incase his table titles had to be short @Leigh

Comment: Yes, thankfully most limits tend to be a bit larger than that. Even oracle allows 30 chars ;-). It is also important table names be descriptive, as there could be multiple entities all having different types of "details".  If there was some context, like if this were a column *within* a table named "Contact", I think it would be a better fit :-)

Answer (score 2):

How about "*routes*" or "*channels*".

Although you would not get to these words using a thesaurus from "contacts", they are common usage among computer programmers, although primarily in an electronic context rather than a database one, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_(communications)).
Here is an example usage for "channel" that is almost exactly what you are asking for:

> The better practice is to send the password "out of band", meaning that you
>   send the file and the password by different communication channels; one on the 
>   internet, and one not. If you send the file by email, send the password by
>   SMS, if the file is on a network share, write the password on paper and 
>   physically give it to them, etc.
>   - from [Mike Ounsworth's comment](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94102/is-it-good-practice-to-send-passwords-in-separate-emails-and-why) on Security.SE

If the database user, as opposed to programmers, is given access to the database tables, then these suggestions would be inappropriate.